# Is there a way to make my shopping cart work with js just by clicking a icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am having trouble making my shopping cart visible just by clicking just need some guidance on making it work. I have attached my html and js below:

```js
//showCart JS - used to make the icon a live button
    
const cart = document.querySelector('#cart');
const cartContent = document.querySelector('.cart-content');
        
cart.addEventListener('click', function() {
  cart.classList.toggle('is-active');
  cartContent.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML - code for the button and icons -->

    <!--Header & LOGO-->
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar__container">
                <a href="/Home.html" id="logo"><img src="images/kingdom/Kingdom TRANS.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 80px; object-fit: fill;"></a>
                <div class="navbar__content">
                    <ul class="navbar__menu">
                        <li class="navbar__item">
                            <a href="/Gallery.html" class="navbar__links">Gallery</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="navbar__item">
                            <a href="/Shop.html" class="navbar__links">Shop</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="navbar__item">
                            <a href="/About.html" class="navbar__links">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="navbar__btn">
                            <span>
                                <button class="cart-btn"><box-icon name='shopping-bag'></box-icon></button>
                            </span>
                            <div class="cart-items" style="font-family: 'Helvetica'; font-size: 16px;">0</div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
    
    <!--Cart-->
        <div class="cart-items" style="font-family: 'Helvetica'; font-size: 16px;">0</div>
         <div class="cart-overlay">
            <div class="cart" id="cart">
                <span class="close-cart">
                    <i class="fas fa-window-close"></i>
                </span>
                <h2>Shopping Bag</h2>
                <div class="cart-content">
                    <div class="cart-item">
                        <img src= "images/Shop/IMG-5288.jpg"
                        alt="product">
                        <div>
                            <h4>Black Sweatsuit</h4>
                            <h5>$85.00</h5>
                            <span class="remove-item" data-id=${item.id}>remove</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
                            <p class="item-amount">1</p>
                            <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the fav-icons just so we can see them here.
1.what I did is that I created a new div called cart-open and put the `svg` icon inside it(you can use favicons).
2.setting cart-content to `display:none` first then adding `display:block` when user clicks.
cart icon will toggle the active class while remove icon will only remove it.
If you have any questions. please let me know

```js
   let cartOpenBtn = document.querySelector(".open-cart")
    const cartCloseBtn = document.querySelector('.close-cart');
    const cartContent = document.querySelector('.cart-content');

    cartOpenBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        cartContent.classList.toggle('active');
    });
    cartCloseBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        cartContent.classList.remove('active');
    })
```

```css
 .cart-content {
        display: none;
    }

    .cart-content.active {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<!-- HTML - code for the button and icons -->

    <!--Header & LOGO-->
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar__container">
            <a href="/Home.html" id="logo"><img src="images/kingdom/Kingdom TRANS.jpg"
                    style="width: 200px; height: 80px; object-fit: fill;"></a>
            <div class="navbar__content">
                <ul class="navbar__menu">
                    <li class="navbar__item">
                        <a href="/Gallery.html" class="navbar__links">Gallery</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar__item">
                        <a href="/Shop.html" class="navbar__links">Shop</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar__item">
                        <a href="/About.html" class="navbar__links">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar__btn">
                        <span>
                            <button class="cart-btn">
                                <box-icon name='shopping-bag'></box-icon>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        <div class="cart-items" style="font-family: 'Helvetica'; font-size: 16px;">0</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <!--Cart-->
                <div class="cart-items" style="font-family: 'Helvetica'; font-size: 16px;">0</div>
                <div class="cart-overlay">
                    <div class="cart" id="cart">
                        <div class="open-cart">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-shopping-cart"
                                width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000000"
                                fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                                <circle cx="6" cy="19" r="2" />
                                <circle cx="17" cy="19" r="2" />
                                <path d="M17 17h-11v-14h-2" />
                                <path d="M6 5l14 1l-1 7h-13" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <span class="close-cart">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-x" width="40"
                                height="40" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="black" fill="none"
                                stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                                <line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18" />
                                <line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18" />
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                        <h2>Shopping Bag</h2>
                        <div class="cart-content">
                            <div class="cart-item">
                                <img src="images/Shop/IMG-5288.jpg" alt="product">
                                <div>
                                    <h4>Black Sweatsuit</h4>
                                    <h5>$85.00</h5>
                                    <span class="remove-item" data-id=${item.id}>remove</span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                        class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-chevron-up" width="40" height="40"
                                        viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="black" fill="none"
                                        stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                                        <polyline points="6 15 12 9 18 15" />
                                    </svg>
                                    <p class="item-amount">1</p>
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                        class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-chevron-down" width="40" height="40"
                                        viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="black" fill="none"
                                        stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                                        <polyline points="6 9 12 15 18 9" />
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Please explain what your answer changes instead of only posting code.

Comment: This wasn't helpful.

Comment: @Royce are you not able to understand it or does it not work as you intended?